# How can I add a function call to my collapsible and display the function return into the collapsible textblock

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add this function

```
function list(){
    var html=" "
    for(var i =0; i<movements.length;i++){
    html+=("<p>" + movements[i][0]+ " " + movements[i][1] + " " + movements[i][2] + "</p>")}
    document.getElementById("listSpace").innerHTML = html;
}
```

to the click of the collapsible and display the return of `list()` into the textblock:

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set" id="myCollapsible">
              <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" >
                  <h3>
                      10 Last movements
                  </h3>
                  <div data-controltype="textblock">
                      <p>
                          <b id="listSpace">
                              10 last movements
                          </b>
                      </p>
                  </div>
              </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a few changes to your code

```
function list() {
    var html = " ", movements = [['10', 'next', 'movements'],['10', 'next', 'movements'],['10', 'next', 'movements']];
    for (var i = 0; i < movements.length; i++) {
        html += ("<p>" + movements[i][0] + " " + movements[i][1] + " " + movements[i][2] + "</p>")
    }
    document.getElementById("listSpace").innerHTML = html;
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div[data-role="collapsible"]').click(list);
});
```

check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6QD3p/)

Comment: Thanks that solves half my problem. Because my movements array gets updated dynamically, how can I attach the function call to the collapsible button so that it gets re-called every time you expand?

Comment: the function list will be called on each click and the updated values will be displayed each time